# How to force element declared in "let" clause in html angular template?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have a component that allows to render a mat-table. For each cell you can specify the value or if it is present, the Component call an ngTemplateOutlet passing it a rendering function retrieved from the calling object.

```
export interface ColumnConfig {
  name: string;
  headerTemplate?: TemplateRef<Element>;
  headerLabel?: string;
  headerClasses?:string;
  bodyTemplate?: TemplateRef<Element>;
  bodyClasses?:string;
  visible?: boolean;
  align?: string;
}
```

```
<mat-cell mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <ng-container *ngIf="!column.bodyTemplate; else bodyTemplate">
        {{ element[column.name] }}
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #bodyTemplate [ngTemplateOutlet]="column.bodyTemplate!" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: element }"></ng-template>
</mat-cell>
```

I've recently updated a lot of project dependencies (typescript, angular, tslint->eslint, ...) and now I get the following error that didn't appear before.

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"$implicit"' does not exist in type 'Element'.
```

I don't understand how to type the element which is defined by the "let" of the "matCellDef".

Tnx!

Comment: Does `column.bodyTemplate!`  has  `let-default` ?

Comment: Do you mean in the caller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it moving ngTemplateOutletContext definition in a TS method:

```
<mat-cell mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <ng-container *ngIf="!column.bodyTemplate; else bodyTemplate">
        {{ element[column.name] }}
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #bodyTemplate [ngTemplateOutlet]="column.bodyTemplate!" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="generateContext(element)"></ng-template>
</mat-cell>
```

Here the TS fragment:

```
public generateContext(element:any):any{
    return {
      $implicit: element
    };
  }
```

If anyone knew how to do this using just the html definitions I would love to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work

```
<mat-cell mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <ng-container *ngIf="!column.bodyTemplate; else bodyTemplate" [ngTemplateOutlet]="bodyTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ element: element }">
        {{ element[column.name] }}
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #bodyTemplate let-element="element">
...
    </ng-template>
</mat-cell>
```